# Using .htaccess mod_rewrite to replace part of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling using .htaccess and mod_rewrite without setting a fixed url or RewriteBase. I want the user to be served "/" when he's trying to access "/login", like this:

If the user tries to access:

```
mydomain.com/login
```

he's actually served

```
mydomain.com/
```

If the user tries to access:

```
mydomain.com/frontend/backend/v1/login
```

he's actually served:

```
mydomain.com/frontend/backend/v1/
```

And similarily for other domains:

```
mydomain2.com/login
```

he's actually served:

```
mydomain2.com/
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: But won't `/frontend/backend/v1/` then serve `/frontend/backend` and then `/frontend` and then `/`?

Comment: It should serve /frontend/backend/v1/. What I'm trying to do is to simply ignore the "login"-part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(?:(.+?)/)?[^/]+/?$ /$1 [L]
```